# jQuery - Datepicker - value of defaultDate problematic

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to find out why defaultDate problem, but I'm stuck.

I have this for example:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="12/03/2012" id="8798044_date"></td>
    <td><font class="red">-39 999,60 €</font></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="8798044" class="date_twr">
    </td>
</tr>
```

and here is the JS code that will work:

```
jQuery('.date_twr').datepicker({
    'changeMonth':true,
    'changeYear':true,
    'dateFormat': 'dd/mm/yy',
    'defaultDate': jQuery('#8798044_date').val()
});
```

the problem is that I do not want to use the id, it is placed in my tests.
I would rather search by "manipulation"

```
jQuery('.date_twr').datepicker({
    'changeMonth':true,
    'changeYear':true,
    'dateFormat': 'dd/mm/yy',
    'defaultDate': jQuery(this).parent().prev().prev().find('input').val()
});
```

Using the click of this class, I know my desired value is correct:

```
jQuery('.date_twr').click({
    console.log(jQuery(this).parent().prev().prev().find('input').val())
});
```

But the search for the default handling does not work.
I searched a bit, but I do not understand why it does not work.
I guess the datepicker element to a special behavior and suddenly the jQuery(this) is not the expected one.

A little help would be welcome :)

Thank you in advance

PS: I use jQuery() instead of $(), because there's several JS libraries on the site I'm working on.

Comment: Could you create an jsfiddle with your problem?

Comment: Did you try to change `this` by `.date_twr` in your datepicker initialization ?
You can use HTML5 `<input type="date" />` instead.

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Architecte/WN5NH/2/

@Bartimeus : As you can see your solution works only if I had one piece, but I have to link each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, in the context of the datepicker it appears that jQuery(this) refers to the document root. This demonstrates HTML as its child.

```
jQuery('.date_twr').datepicker({
    'appendText': jQuery(this).children().first().prop('tagName')
});
```

Strangely, doing it within an each loop seems to work

```
jQuery('.date_twr').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).datepicker({
        'changeMonth':true,
        'changeYear':true,
        'dateFormat': 'dd/mm/yy',
        'defaultDate': jQuery(this).parent().prev().prev().find('input').val()
    });
});
```

Edit: this pulls through the correct values but datepicker seems to parse them incorrectly and you get some odd results. This forces the date parsing in the correct format and passes the date object to the date picker:

```
jQuery('.date_twr').each(function() {
    var dt = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', jQuery(this).parent().prev().prev().find('input').val());
    jQuery(this).datepicker({
        'changeMonth': true,
        'changeYear': true,
        'dateFormat': 'dd/mm/yy',
        'defaultDate': dt
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks of lot for your explication and your multiples solutions ;)